# How to use onclick event after an image generated by php code?

Tags: php, javascript, html, image, onclick

I am creating an image which is a graph, plotting days and no of documents created on each day. 
I am using php to create image.
Now, to get more details about the query, I want to enable the user to click on the image created and redirect him to more details, which is a table.
Could anyone suggest me how to use onclick event...?

```
<html> 
<body>
<script>
function details() 
{
     document.getElementById("imageform").submit();
}
</script>
<form name="imageform" id="imageform" method="get" action="resultdocument.php" >
<img border="0" src="<?php graphytry.php/img.png ?>" width="304" height="228" onclick="details()"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S:- Image is created in the same script, just above this HTML code.

The PHP code :-

```
    <?php
# ------- The graph values in the form of associative array
$xaxis="Jan";
$yaxis=110; 
$values=array(
    $xaxis => $yaxis,
    );
$img_width=450;
$img_height=300; 
$margins=20;

# ---- Find the size of graph by substracting the size of borders
$graph_width=$img_width - $margins * 2;
$graph_height=$img_height - $margins * 2; 
$img=imagecreate($img_width,$img_height);

$bar_width=20;
$total_bars=count($values);
$gap= ($graph_width- $total_bars * $bar_width ) / ($total_bars +1);

# -------  Define Colors ----------------
$bar_color=imagecolorallocate($img,0,64,128);
$background_color=imagecolorallocate($img,240,240,255);
$border_color=imagecolorallocate($img,200,200,200);
$line_color=imagecolorallocate($img,220,220,220);

# ------ Create the border around the graph ------

imagefilledrectangle($img,1,1,$img_width-2,$img_height-2,$border_color);
imagefilledrectangle($img,$margins,$margins,$img_width-1-$margins,$img_height-1-$margins,$background_color);


# ------- Max value is required to adjust the scale -------
$max_value=max($values);
$ratio= $graph_height/$max_value;


# -------- Create scale and draw horizontal lines  --------
$horizontal_lines=20;
$horizontal_gap=$graph_height/$horizontal_lines;

for($i=1;$i<=$horizontal_lines;$i++){
    $y=$img_height - $margins - $horizontal_gap * $i ;
    imageline($img,$margins,$y,$img_width-$margins,$y,$line_color);
    //$v=intval($horizontal_gap * $i /$ratio);
    //imagestring($img,0,5,$y-5,$v,$bar_color);

}


# ----------- Draw the bars here ------
for($i=0;$i<$total_bars; $i++){ 
    # ------ Extract key and value pair from the current pointer position
    list($key,$value)=each($values); 
    $x1= $margins + $gap + $i * ($gap+$bar_width) ;
    $x2= $x1 + $bar_width; 
    $y1=$margins +$graph_height- intval($value * $ratio) ;
    $y2=$img_height-$margins;
    imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$y1-10,$value,$bar_color);
    imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$img_height-15,$key,$bar_color);       
    imagefilledrectangle($img,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$bar_color);
}
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($img);?>
```

Comment: Can you also post your PHP Code?

Comment: No `onclick` needed here. Just replace the form with a hyperlink and your done `<a href="resultdocument.php"><img /></a>`

Comment: Its a bit long, I will try to post it.

Comment: @Andreas As I am new to html, would you please try to write the entire <a href> tag..? You suggested I should use.?

Comment: `<a href="resultdocument.php"><img border="0" src="<?php graphytry.php/img.png ?>" width="304" height="228"></a>`

Comment: <a href="resultdocument.php"><img border="0" src="<?php graphytry.php/img.png ?>" width="304" height="228"></a>
This did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the option of creating `image map` and generate x1,y1, x2,y2 co-ordinates for click event with separate AJAX request, if you need to have multiple clicks on image instead of single click.

More about image map : [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

If you are just looking for single click, then as @Andreas suggested, use below

<a href="resultdocument.php"><img /></a>

Comment: :- Nope it did not work <a href> tag as you can see the image is created by the php code, i need to provide proper reference it seems.

Comment: Minesh the example you shared from w3schools.com. Looked at it.
Would it be possible to use "Click for More details" as the tag to the next php page.?

Comment: @Ameya, yes why not, you can specify the URL of next page in href attribute of map area tag.

Comment: Minesh:-
<html>
<body>
<img src="/graphtry.php/image.png" width="450" height="300" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" href="resultdocument.php" alt="Sun"></map>
</body>
</html>
This code is not working. I want to know is my syntax correct..?
Am I correctly referring the image object created.?

Comment: @Ameya what is the problem you are facing ? Make sure image source is correct src="/graphtry.php/image.png"

Comment: Well It seems when I create the image with the php code it is not saved on my server and hence, HTML code is unable to use it for next steps.